# Passing HTTP authenticated principal onto another worker thread

Tags: asp.net, impersonation, principal

We have a web front end on our business layer server.

Certain pages in our web application instantiate very long running tasks (could be up to 10+ minutes).  The way that these requests are handled is like so: -

(on the HTTP request thread)

- we make a connection to the business server.
- we create a new thread to make the long running call passing in the connection object.
- The HTTP request then completes, passing a handle back to the browser,
- the browser periodically polls the web server to get updates on the long running task progress.

All requests to the business server are authenticated - the connection's user principal page must have permission to call the method on the business server.

This mechanism works fine as long as our web application is running in Classic mode.
When we run in pipeline mode, we get ObjectDisposedExceptions when the browser polls.

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Safe handle has been closed
at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.SafeHandleC2NHelper(Object pThis, IntPtr CleanupWorkList)
at Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.GetTokenInformation(SafeTokenHandle TokenHandle, UInt32 TokenInformationClass, SafeLocalAllocHandle TokenInformation, UInt32 TokenInformationLength, ref UInt32 ReturnLength)
at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetTokenInformation(SafeTokenHandle tokenHandle, TokenInformationClass tokenInformationClass, ref UInt32 dwLength)
at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.get_User()
at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetName()
at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.get_Name()
```

the problem appears to be that the windows principal used to make the connection is disposed when the original request ends (which is understandable - in fact I am surprised that the code worked at all!).

As a way around this problem I was wondering if it was possible to either create a duplicate of the HTTP request principal and use that to create the connection (and dispose of it when the long running task completes) or would it be possible to impersonate the HTTP request principle on the worker thread even after the principal is disposed?

**Update**

(My comment under Aliostad's question was incorrect: the test page did fail.  I managed to confuse myself sufficiently that I wrote my test page so that it did not exercise the same code path as the real (faulting) code.  Nevermind!)

I have written a "workaround" for this problem: -
I am in the fortunate position of knowing what roles/groups the business server logic will be querying for before the call to the business server is made.  So my workaround is to create a new generic principal based upon the request's principal's membership of these roles.  The long running task is run using the generic principal.

I am not 100% happy with this workaround because it is very much a "hack" - i.e. I can see that it would easily fall down if some logic did the (eminently sensible) check of verifying that the principal's identity is authenticated.

So I would still very much appreciate any help / insight into this issue.

Thanks

Comment: What a great question. I will have a look at lunchtime.

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is my catch on this.

First of all, if you create a thread, all the current thread's security context will be copied to the new thread - by default. This operation is heavy but much needed (as you can imagine most things will not work without it). In case you need to prevent it and you do not need the copying of context, there is a way to do it and it has been explained in Richter's C# via CLR. Lucky enough, he has shared this very bit of the book [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/01/27/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx) and basically calling a static method to prevent context to be `flowed`:

```
ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow();
```

I cannot think this is being called in WCF although using Reflector, I found a single use of it in here:

```
  [SecuritySafeCritical]
    private IAsyncResult BeginGetContext(bool startListening)
    {
        Exception exception;
        do
        {
            exception = null;
            try
            {
                try
                {
                    if (ExecutionContext.IsFlowSuppressed())
                    {
                        return this.listener.BeginGetContext(this.onGetContext, null);
                    }
                    using (ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow())
                    {
                        return this.listener.BeginGetContext(this.onGetContext, null);
                    }
                }
                // .... the rest
```

Interestingly enough, this is used in 3 places one of them in `SharedHttpTransportManager`.

Now all this might look like we have found the issue and it is a bug but I very much doubt it.

My hunch is that there is a **process recycling happening in between and the context is lost**. The way to prove or disprove this would be to use perfmon to register all process recycles and find out if any was in between.

My solution is basically - which you might not like! - to simply insert an item into a queue (MSMQ or a simple database queue) and have a windows service reading it. With this operation being so important, *I would never trust IIS to carry out to the finish.*

Hope this is useful to you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have checked that there is no process recycling happening between requests.  Your assertion that creating a new thread automatically copies all the security context led me to knock up a simple test page to (what I thought) reproduce the bug.  The test page just spawns a thread that keeps calling a method on the business server every second or so.  (To my surprise) the test page worked!  So I can only now presume that there is some processing going on in my proper page that is causing the problem.  I will investigate more.